# Unwanted letterboxing using Wirecast

Tags: video, software

When I create a 1280 x 720 pixel image in Photoshop CS5.1 for use as a title slide in Wirecast, the resulting image is letterboxed.   I have a similar problem with 720p video feeds from a Black Magic Ultrastudio 3D.

Can anyone tell me how to find the set-up parameters to fix this.  I'm suspecting it's a pixel aspect ratio problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it is the 'canvas size' setting under the top level Broadcast menu. If you are broadcasting at anything less than 1280x720, then try to keep the aspect ratio the same for the lower resolution, i.e. something like 640x360